# Heroku: managing/switching between personal and work accounts

Tags: heroku

Using heroku was easy when I was only using it for a few pet projects. Now I want to use multiple accounts (professional vs personal) and am having a hard time getting this to work (logins, ssh keys, etc). I can't find any documentation or recommended workflow, so how do you manage switching accounts to create/push apps on heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [heroku-accounts](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) plugin solves this issue.

However, even though it's a solid plugin, be aware that it manipulates your git config settings under the covers which can, occasionally cause some issues or unintuitive errors. If you have a good handle on how Heroku works in relation to your git config/remotes it's a good option.

Comment: Heroku accounts plugin is definitely the way to go - it should be part of the core Heroku gem :)

Comment: Looks like there have been some updates to the plugin since I last tried it. It also looked like I tried using it in the past so there were some remnants of the plugin that I didn't realize were interfering with my git pushes. Anyway, updating the plugin and trying it again resolved my issues.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer an option since heroku cli automatically uninstalls it `Uninstalling deprecated ddollar/heroku-accounts plugin... done`

Answer (score 7):

I had this plugin installed before and used with the heroku gem.

Today, I
- uninstalled the gem
- installed heroku-toolbelt
- installed the heroku-accounts plugin again

but every time I tried to use the `heroku` command, I was getting an error:

```
 'No such account: personal'
```

Problem was that my `.gitconfig` still had a setting that said:

```
[heroku]
account = personal
```

Once removed, all is good.

I also along the way, removed any references to heroku from `.ssh/config`

Comment: Removing that info from the `.git/config` file worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It worked out for me, but I only to replaced 'personal' on that same line:

```
[heroku]
```

account = personal

with the original working name that I had before(in my case was 'work').

```
[heroku]
```

account = work

After that, I was able to use the heroku-accounts again and logged in without any other changes.